# Implementing a struct that can have parents/children

Tags: c

So I am trying to implement a UNIX filesystem and am having some trouble because I haven't used structs that much before. I am fairly new to programming. This is what I have right now:

```
typedef struct Unix{
    char *name;
    struct Unix *parentDirectory;
    struct Unix **subDirectories;
} FileSystem;
```

I have this in a separate file called Unix.c that is passed into my main.c file via a header. parentDirectory will be a pointer to the parent directory, and subDirectories will be pointers to all of the subdirectories.

My question is how I would access the directories and subdirectories in my main file. The other question I have is the following: Let's say I have the following created: `/home/TestUser/Desktop/StephCurry/WithTheShot`. If I delete directory StephCurry, how would I change all of the other parent/sub directory structs above that directory? I believe this has something to do with data structures but I am not 100% sure.

Thanks guys. I am really enjoying getting into programming, it's pretty fun! I'm just having some trouble implementing some of this stuff.

Comment: If you are fairly new to programming why are you implementing a `UNIX filesystem`?

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but if you are just starting to learn C and programming, writing your own file system if probably a bit of a stretch.  Maybe start with some smaller, more narrowly-focuses exercises?

Comment: Are you trying to make in memory model of file system?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how I would access the directories and subdirectories
>   in my main file.

```
// example: print given directory and all subdirectories recursively
void prdirr(FileSystem *dir)
{
    puts(dir->name);
    FileSystem **subdirp = dir->subDirectories;
    if (subdirp)
        for (; *subdirp; ++subdirp)
            prdirr(*subdirp);
}
...
    FileSystem root = { "", NULL, calloc(1, sizeof (FileSystem *)) };
    ...
    prdirr(&root);
```

> The other question I have is the following: Let's say I have the
>   following created: `/home/TestUser/Desktop/StephCurry/WithTheShot`. If I
>   delete directory StephCurry, how would I change all of the other
>   parent/sub directory structs above that directory?

You don't have to *change all of the other parent/sub directory structs* - you just have to remove the directory `StephCurry` from `subDirectories` of its parent `Desktop` (and `free` the deleted structs if they have been `malloc`ed, of course). Let's assume `dir` points to the node `StephCurry`:

```
// free memory of given directory and all subdirectories recursively
void dedirr(FileSystem *dir)
{
    FileSystem **subdirp = dir->subDirectories;
    if (subdirp)
        for (; *subdirp; ++subdirp)
            dedirr(*subdirp), free(*subdirp);   // free the node
    free(dir->subDirectories);  // free the list
}
...
    // remove dir from parent's list of subDirectories
    if (dir->parentDirectory)   // won't remove root
    {
        FileSystem **subl, **subr;
        subl = subr = dir->parentDirectory->subDirectories;
        do if (*subr == dir) ++subr; while (*subl++ = *subr++);
        dedirr(dir);    // free memory of deleted dir tree
    }
```